# How to prove that $(\sin\frac{1}{n}+\cos\frac{1}{n})\geqslant (\sin\frac{1}{n+1}+\cos\frac{1}{n+1})$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove, if  $n>0$,  that $$\left(\sin\frac{1}{n}+\cos\frac{1}{n}\right)\geqslant \left(\sin\frac{1}{n+1}+\cos\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x)=\sin x+\cos x$ for $0<x<\pi/4$, then $\varphi'(x)=\cos x-\sin x>0$ for $0<x<\pi/4$, so for $n\geq 2$, we have $1/(n+1)<1/n$ and hence $\varphi(1/(n+1))<\varphi(1/n)$.

For 
\begin{align*}
\sin 1+\cos 1-(\sin(1/2)+\cos(1/2))&=\sqrt{2}[\sin(1+\pi/4)-\sin(1/2+\pi/4)]\\
&=2\sqrt{2}\cos((3+\pi)/4)\sin(1/4)\\
&>0,
\end{align*}
note that $(3+\pi)/4<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

1. $\displaystyle\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$;
2. $\displaystyle 0\le x_1\le x_2 \le \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow 0\le \sin(x_1)\le \sin(x_2) \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n$ is positive integer, it is:
$$\sin \frac{1}{n} -\sin \frac{1}{n+1}\ge \cos \frac{1}{n+1} -\cos \frac{1}{n} \iff$$
$$2\cos \frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)} \cdot \sin \frac{1}{2n(n+1)} \ge 2\sin \frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\cdot \sin \frac{1}{2n(n+1)} \iff$$
$$\cos \frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\ge \sin \frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}, 0<\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}<\frac{\pi}{4}.$$